# Orchard CMS BlogML old entries

Tags: content-management-system, blogs, orchardcms, blogml

I want to import old blog posts into Orchard CMS's blog module.

These are not contained in any xml format, if I try to add them manually then my posts display by creation date which ruins the order of original creation date of my blog. I noticed with Windows Live Writer I can set the Publish date but this still does not effect the Creation date.

There is a module called BlogML, but my blogs are not in RSS format. I see the BlogML.xsd is here http://blogml.org/, but is there some software I can use to generate the correct XML which I can then import into Orchard? And will this fix the creation date at all? I think I may be left in creating a custom type say 'imported blog' and add extra fields on which I can sort by.

Answer (score 0):

If you are so worried about the creation date, you could just go into the database manually and change the creation date for each blog entry.  Would take a lot less time than anything else.

Comment: good point i'll do that. the issue being that blogs are organised by creation date only which is no good if you want to restore a historical blog

Comment: It would work, but looking into Orchard's db structure, it looks untidy and has multiple entries for 1 blog item, this might work on a new installation of the site.